# Multi-project job scheduling in OptaPlanner

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am a Java/C/Python developer who is looking to assist a relative who manages a *custom* product shop.  I am new to optaplanner and contraint programming in general, so my questions are:

1.) Is the scheduling problem below *likely* solvable in optaplanner (or one of its alternatives)?

2.) What kind of algorithm is best suited for this problem?  It seems like it has a close resemblance to the [Project job scheduling](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#projectJobScheduling) example given in the (excellent) OptaPlanner documentation, but it has the additional constraint of scheduling multiple projects at any given time.

The simplified problem is:

- At any given time, there are 1 to *n* projects.
- Each project has its own deadline.
- Each project has a sequenced series of jobs.
- The domain for jobs is limited to **cutting**, **sanding**, and **painting**.
- Any given job can appear 0 to many times in the sequence (i.e. not all projects have an 'cutting' job, but may have multiple 'painting' jobs)
- Each project shares global resources, namely employees ***A***, ***B***, and ***C***.
- Employee ***A*** can only perform the **cutting** and **sanding** jobs
- Employee ***B*** can only perform the **cutting**, **sanding**, and **painting** jobs
- Employee ***C*** can only perform the **sanding** and **painting** jobs
- Solutions only need to be feasible, not optimal

Comment: You could map the multi-project problem into a single project by adding a node that has a deadline. You then add constraints that the deadline date has to be met on each group of tasks. As for feasibility, you have the option of terminating the search once all hard constraints are met; everything after that is gravy. In the example you gave, each book could be seen as a separate project.

Comment: "...each book could be seen as a separate project."  Wow - I did NOT read that problem carefully.  Thank you for pointing that out!  Those are great suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take OptaPlanner's "Project job scheduling" example and adjust it accordingly:

- "there are 1 to n projects": The "Project job scheduling" example already has multiple projects.
- "Each project has its own deadline." Add a hard constraint that the last job of a project must end before the project deadline. Make sure penalize the amount of time it's too late (see "score trap" in docs).
- "sequenced series of jobs": configure the precedence constraints accordingly
- "Any given job can appear 0 to many times in the sequence": each of those times is a separate job in the example-terminology.
- "Each project shares global resources, namely employees A, B, and C": global, renewable resources
- Solutions only need to be feasible, not optimal: Yet, I 'd still keep using the soft constraint to minimize the makespan.

Note: OptaPlanner 6.0 solves the "Project job scheduling" example pretty good already, but improvements planned for 6.1 are likely to improve results even more.